# Convert RGB Image to Grayscale Image in DLIB

Tags: c++, image-processing, dlib

How can I convert a `dlib::array2d<bgr_pixel>` to gray Image?

The gray Image should be `array2d<unsigned_char>`.

I never see a good dlib documentation on that issue.

Answer (score 11):

dlib::array2d is an image already, you can use it for any dlib's image functions

load image:

```
dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel> img_rgb;
dlib::load_image(img_rgb, "test_image.jpg");
```

convert to greyscale:

```
dlib::array2d<unsigned char> img_gray;
dlib::assign_image(img_gray, img_rgb);
```

converto to OpenCV Image (cv::Mat):

```
#include <dlib/opencv.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
cv::Mat img = dlib::toMat(img_gray);
```

get image from OpenCV:

```
#include <dlib/opencv.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
cv::Mat img = cv::imread("test_image.jpg")
dlib::cv_image<rgb_pixel> dlib_img(img); // only stores pointer, no deep copy
```

Documentation is [here](http://dlib.net/imaging.html). There are a lot of well-documented examples, you should start from them. [Special example about array2d](http://dlib.net/image_ex.cpp.html)

Comment: I have opencv gray mat and not rgb, how can I convert it to dlib image?

Comment: @user924 instead of `rgb_pixel` use `unsigned char`